# Create "buffer" matrix from dataframe with rolling window?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Given a dataframe of just one column, how can I convert it into another dataframe "buffer" (of size 2), described below:

df =

```
   0
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  4
4  4
5  5
6  5
```

expected_buffer =

```
   0 1
0  1 2
1  2 3
2  3 4 
3  4 5
```

This is my attempt:

```
def buff(df,past):
    arr1=df.values
    arr=arr1[0:past]
    for i in xrange(past,df.shape[0]-past+2):
        arr=np.append(arr,arr1[i:past+i],axis=0)
    return pd.DataFrame(arr)
```

Which returns the following:

```
   0
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  4
4  4
5  5
6  5
```

How to get the expected buff output ?

EDIT:
By `past` I mean the buffer size. Using MATLAB notations: I have 5 element column vector

```
df = [1;2;3;4;5]
```

If `past` is 2, I should end up getting the following output:

```
buff = [1 2; 2 3; 3 4; 4 5]
```

If `past` is 3, then expected output should be

```
buff = [1 2 3; 2 3 4; 3 4 5]
```

If `past` is 4, then expected output is

```
buff = [1 2 3 4; 2 3 4 5]
```

So for `n`-element `df` and `past=m`, I would get a matrix of size `(n-past+1)`x`past`.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you want. Can you describe in words what your `buffer` is supposed to be?

Comment: `rr = pd.Series([0,1,2,3,4,4,5,5]); pd.DataFrame(data = {'A':rr, 'B':rr.shift(-1).dropna()})`?

Comment: How do know where the buffer starts?

Comment: @AlbertoGarcia-Raboso buffer is essentially a sliding window. So if we have n element data. I want to take m at a time (m<n) in a row while sliding the first element in every row by 1. Hope that's clear

Comment: what do you pass as the `past` parameter?

Comment: No, it's not clear. I don't understand the "while sliding...", and the part before that seems to me what @piRSquared answered --- and that does not match your expected output.

Comment: @piRSquared : hi, by past I mean the buffer size. let me use MATLAB notations in here. I have 5 element column vector df = [1;2;3;4;5], if past is 2, I should end up getting the following output: buff= [1 2; 2 3; 3 4; 4 5]. If past is 3, then expected output should be [1 2 3; 2 3 4; 3 4 5]. If past is 4, then expected output is [1 2 3 4; 2 3 4 5]. So for n-element df and past=m, I would get a matrix of (n-past+1) X past matrix. In my question I have shown my expected output. Does this help?

Comment: @AlbertoGarcia-Raboso : Just replied to piRSquared in above comments

Comment: The information you provided in your response to me should be in the body of your question.  Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @piRSquared: edited the question.

Answer (score 3):

```
def buff(df, past):
    a = np.concatenate([df.values[i:i-past] for i in range(past)], axis=1)
    return pd.DataFrame(a, columns=list(range(past)))
```

---

```
buff(df, 2)
```

[image]

```
buff(df, 3)
```

[image]

```
buff(df, 4)
```

[image]

```
buff(df, 5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
import pandas as pd

def buff(s, n):
    return (pd.concat([s.shift(-i) for i in range(n)], axis=1)
              .dropna().astype(int))

s = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5])
print(buff(s, 2))

#    0  0
# 0  1  2
# 1  2  3
# 2  3  4
# 3  4  5

print(buff(s, 3))

#    0  0  0
# 0  1  2  3
# 1  2  3  4
# 2  3  4  5

print(buff(s, 4))

#    0  0  0  0
# 0  1  2  3  4
# 1  2  3  4  5
```