# Create matrix from vector's rolling window

Tags: r

I would like to do something like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39041769/create-buffer-matrix-from-dataframe-with-rolling-window) but in R.

Given:

```
> my_vector
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

And `window_size = 3`, I would like to get the following matrix:

```
> my_matrix
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    2    3    4
[3,]    3    4    5
[4,]    4    5    6
```

As you can see, every row of the matrix is a window of the vector.

Is there any efficient way to do it in R without `for` loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `embed`

```
apply(embed(my_vector, 4), 1, rev)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    2    3
#[2,]    2    3    4
#[3,]    3    4    5
#[4,]    4    5    6
```

---

Or it can be modified to

```
t(embed(rev(my_vector), 4))[, 3:1]
```

Or as @lmo suggested

```
embed(my_vector, 3)[, 3:1]
```

---

Or with `matrix`

```
matrix(my_vector, 7, 3)[1:4,]
```

Comment: Minor modification `embed(1:6, 3)[, 3:1]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
sapply(1:3, function(i) my_vector[i:(i+3)])
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    2    3
#[2,]    2    3    4
#[3,]    3    4    5
#[4,]    4    5    6
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using `rollapply` in zoo:

```
library(zoo)

rollapply(my_vector, 3, c)
```

giving:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    2    3    4
[3,]    3    4    5
[4,]    4    5    6
```

**Note:** The input used above, in reproducible form, is:

```
my_vector <- 1:6
```